# large field in mongodb document is slowing down aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named "questions" with around 15 fields. There is an indexed field called "user". Another field is "response_api" which is a subdocument of around 60KB. And there are around 40000 documents in this collection.

When I run aggreate query with only $match stage on user field, it is very slow and takes around 11 seconds to complete.
The query is:

```
db.questions.aggregate([{$match: {user: ObjectId("5c9a19abc89b2d09740ccd1d")} }])
```

But when I run this same query with $project stage, it returns pretty fast in less than 10 millis. The query is:

```
db.questions.aggregate([{$match: {user: ObjectId("5c9a19abc89b2d09740ccd1d")} }, {$project: {_id: 1, user: 1, subject: 1}}])
```

Note: This particular user has 5000 documents in questions collection.

When I copied this collection without "response_api" field and created index on user field, then both these queries on the copied collection were pretty fast and took less than 10 millis.

Can somebody explain What's going on here? Is it because of that large field?

Comment: Makes sense that a query that includes a large field would be much slower than one without it, right?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Yeah, that's exectly what's happening. But... I noticed a weird behaviour recently that if I run the "find" query rather than aggregate, it runs pretty fast with and without large field. This behaviour makes this question even more weird

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/) documentation provided by MongoDB, you should keep a check on the size of indexes. Basically, if index size is more than what your RAM can accomadate, then MongoDB will be reading them from the disk and thus your queries will be a lot slower.

Comment: Size of the index is common in both situations, then why query is slow in the first case?